# In Kivy, how do I close a Popup using a close button from another class?

Tags: python, popup, kivy, kivy-language

I need to close a Popup in kivy using some close button.

I've found some solutions here but it's not compatible with the ScreenManager i'm currently using. To show my popup like i want i use a FloatLayout and pass it as content for a popup.
When i use the function close it calls inside de FloatLayout class and doesn't work. So how can I close the popup in the MainWindow?

Here is my code:

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

    class MainWindow(Screen):
        def open(self):
            pop = Pop()
            popup = Popup(title="",
                          content=pop,
                          size_hint=(.8, .8))
            popup.open()

    class Pop(FloatLayout):
        def close(self):
            self.dismiss()

    class Setting(Screen):
        pass

    class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
        pass

    kv = Builder.load_file("teste.kv")

    class TesteApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return kv

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        TesteApp().run()
```

And for my kv file:

```
    #:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
    #:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

    WindowManager:
        MainWindow:
        Setting:


    <MainWindow>:
        name: "main"

        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8}
                size_hint:0.5, 0.5
                text: "TITLE"
                font_size: (root.width/30 + root.height/30)

            Button:
                pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
                size_hint:0.6, 0.1
                text: "Set"
                on_release:
                    app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left')
                    app.root.current = "setting"

            Button:
                pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .25}
                size_hint:0.6,0.1
                text: "Pop"
                on_release:
                    root.open()


    <Setting>:
        name: "setting"

        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Set Time'
                pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .75}
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                font_size: (root.width/30 + root.height/30)

            Button:
                pos_hint:{'center_x': .1, 'center_y': .1}
                size_hint:0.05,0.05
                on_release:
                    app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='right')
                    app.root.current = 'main'

    <Pop>:
        Label:
            text: 'Popup text'
            size_hint: .4, .15
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .7}
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"

        Button:
            text: "Close"
            size_hint: .4, .15
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .15}
            on_release: root.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by saving a reference to the `Popup` in your `open()` method and placing the `close()` method in the same class. In your modified code below, the `Close` button now calls the `close()` method of the `MainWindow`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class MainWindow(Screen):
    def open(self):
        pop = Pop()
        self.popup = Popup(title="",
                      content=pop,
                      size_hint=(.8, .8))
        self.popup.open()

    def close(self):
        self.popup.dismiss()


class Pop(FloatLayout):
    pass


class Setting(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    Setting:


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8}
            size_hint:0.5, 0.5
            text: "TITLE"
            font_size: (root.width/30 + root.height/30)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
            size_hint:0.6, 0.1
            text: "Set"
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left')
                app.root.current = "setting"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .25}
            size_hint:0.6,0.1
            text: "Pop"
            on_release:
                root.open()


<Setting>:
    name: "setting"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Set Time'
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .75}
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width/30 + root.height/30)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .1, 'center_y': .1}
            size_hint:0.05,0.05
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='right')
                app.root.current = 'main'

<Pop>:
    Label:
        text: 'Popup text'
        size_hint: .4, .15
        pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .7}
        halign: "center"
        valign: "center"

    Button:
        text: "Close"
        size_hint: .4, .15
        pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .15}
        on_release: app.root.get_screen('main').close()
        # if you are sure the current screen will still be "main":
        # on_release: app.root.current_screen.close()
''')


class TesteApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TesteApp().run()
```